# Connecting My Android Phone to my computer for Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, xml, build

Please if you can help. With my Android Studio 4.0, my emulator works fine and now I want to connect my android phone LG Stylo 4 to Android Studio, so I can build apps with my phone device, so my computer device manager recognizes my phone and Android Studio 4.0 doesn't recognize my phone when I hit the Run App button. I searched the internet for solutions and found a few. I replaced the USB cable from phone to computer and still, Android Studio doesn't recognize my phone with logcat. Are there settings on my computer that need to be looked at like allowing my device to access Android Studio 4.0. My device manager shows my phone and all drivers are updated. Any help is needed, please.

Comment: You should probably enable developer mode on your mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find 'Developer options' in settings on your android device and turn ON usb debugging. Developer options are not visible by default. I think if you go to Settings -> About phone -> Build number. Click 5-7 times on the build number and developer options should be enabled.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213702/lg-stylo-4-debugging#:~:text=To%20enable%20Developer%20Options%2C%20navigate,tap%20Build%20number%20seven%20times.&text=Tap%20USB%20debugging%20to%20enable%20or%20disable.